# Behavior of server-side Transactions in Firestore

Tags: firebase, google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-firestore, transactions, locking

When I run a transaction using Firestore's server client library(it's pessimistic lock), my understanding is that it does not allow writes from others, but allows reads.

Further, in terms of the behavior of that transaction, I understand that the first read succeeds, but fails on its write, and the transaction is re-executed a second time.

In this case, is it possible to get the first write failure with try-catch and in case of an error, have another function executed instead of retrying the transaction a second time?

Namely, I don't want the transaction to retry once it fails due to a conflict with other transaction.

Comment: Which library in particular are you referring to?  Have a link?

Comment: Thanks for your comment. I'm referring to Firebase Admin SDK or Google Cloud client library. Both seem to function as the same, speaking about pessimistic lock of the transaction. 

https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/client/libraries?hl=en

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Further, in terms of the behavior of that transaction, I understand
> that the first read succeeds, but fails on its write, and the
> transaction is re-executed a second time.

No, this is not the behaviour of a Transaction with the server client libraries which use pessimistic concurrency controls to resolve data contention.

As explained in the [documentation](https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/transaction-data-contention?hl=en&authuser=0#data_contention_in_the_server_client_libraries), "pessimistic transactions use database locks to prevent other operations from **modifying data**". "A transaction's lock on a document blocks other transactions, batched writes, and non-transactional writes from changing that document".

In other words, pessimistic transactions **will not fail because a write operation from outside the transaction tries to write on the documents read by the transaction**. It will block the "outside writes" until it releases its document locks at commit time. The transaction is **not** "re-executed a second time".

> I don't want the transaction to retry once it fails due to a conflict
> with other transaction.

"When a transaction locks a document, other write operations must wait for the transaction to release its lock. **Transactions acquire their locks in chronological order**."

Comment: "Mr. Renaud Tarnec, thank you for your response. Is my understanding below correct in a Transaction with the server client libraries in Firestore? 

Example: Consider the case where TransactionA has locked Document C and TransactionB wants to perform a transaction on Document C.

① TransactionB reads DocumentC once 
② Upon confirming the lock status, it waits until the lock is released. 
③ Once TransactionA’s lock is released, TransactionB acquires its own lock. Does this acquisition imply that TransactionB reads DocumentC AGAIN?"

Comment: Yes Transaction B has to read the document C again because this document may have been modified by Transaction A.

Comment: Understood. Thanks for your sharing, Mr. Renaud Tarnec.